# How to increase max size of copied text in JetBrains products, specifically WebStorm and IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I work with pretty large text/json files and the attached screenshot popped into my face.
How can I increase the max size of copied content in JetBrains Products?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help | Edit Custom Properties:

```
idea.max.content.load.filesize=50000
```

The size is in kilobytes.